# Xamarin C# button reference doesnt exist in current context

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, binding

Im using Xamarin to develop an application

Basically an admin user should be able to have access to this button. I have used this logic previously and has worked fine.

A regular user should not have access to hide other regular users reviews.

I was told there is issue with it being nested within a carousel view.

I could restructure the whole thing but i like the design currently being used

The XAML code is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="GOV.ReviewPage" Title="Reviews" >

<Grid RowDefinitions="20,180,20,32,230,90" ColumnDefinitions="20,*,20">
        <Frame Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Grid.RowSpan="2">
        <CarouselView x:Name="MainCarousel" IndicatorView="indicatorView" IsBounceEnabled="True" >
            <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                        <ScrollView>
                            <Grid  RowDefinitions="20,20,*" ColumnDefinitions="75,*" Margin="15,0,25,0">
                                <Label Text="Username:" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" />
                                <Label Text="{Binding User.Username}" FontSize="15" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"  HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" />
                                <Label Text="Description:" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" />
                                    <Label Text="{Binding Description}" FontSize="15" HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>

                                <Frame Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" >
                                    <Button x:Name="HideButtonRef" Clicked="HideButton" Text="{Binding stringVal}" 
                                            HeightRequest="50" />
                                </Frame>

                            </Grid>
                        </ScrollView>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
        </CarouselView>
        </Frame> 
    </Grid>
</ContentPage>
```

and The problematic C# logic:

```
        protected override async void OnAppearing()
        {
            if (User.Admin) { HideButtonRef.IsEnabled = false; } // this doesnt work for some reason
            else {HideButtonRef.IsEnabled = true; }
            base.OnAppearing();
            await LoadList();
        }
```

The c# logic says " the name 'HideButtonRef' does not exist in the current context"

Comment: there are dozens and dozens of existing questions like this.  An element in a template cannot be referenced by name.  Use data binding to set it's properties instead.

Answer (score 0):

Create a property on the codebehind to bind to. You have to make sure the ViewModel implements INotifyPropertyChanged:

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
{
    var handler = PropertyChanged;
    if (handler != null)
    {
        handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Then create a property that holds the value of whether or not to show the button.

```
bool _isAdmin;
public bool IsAdmin
{
    get {return _isAdmin;}
    set 
    {
        _isAdmin = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("IsAdmin");
    }
 }
```

Then change the button definition in the XAML to:

```
<Button x:Name="HideButtonRef"
        Clicked="HideButton"
        Text="{Binding stringVal}"
        IsVisible="{Binding IsAdmin}"
        HeightRequest="50" />
```

And the OnAppearing now becomes

```
protected override async void OnAppearing()
    {
        IsAdmin = !User.Admin;
        base.OnAppearing();
        await LoadList();
    }
```